# Codeigniter parser library stopped working

Tags: codeigniter, parsing, codeigniter-3

We moved our codeigniter application to new server and the parser library stopped working, it should parse the `{content}` with the view we have loaded, its been working on the old server

```
    $data = array(
        'content'   => $view,
        'title' => $title,
    );

    $ci->parser->parse('index', $data);
```

we are on php7, and ci version 3.1.7
wondering if any php extension needs to be installed on the server?

Comment: Have you loaded the library yet? `$this->load->library('parser');` on autoload.php under config folder.

Comment: yes the same code is working on different server

Comment: Based [CI parser Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html) is it not necessary to use parser class is it **not** a full blown parsing solution.